# Maven unable to pass arguments into main

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to maven and trying to run a echo netty server. I am running the program in Intellij but the main function is unable to pick up the argument I defined in the pom.xml. 
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>NettyExperiment</groupId>
    <artifactId>NettyExperiment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.50.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <echo-server.hostname>localhost</echo-server.hostname>
        <echo-server.port>8888</echo-server.port>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-server</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>chapter2.server.EchoServer</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${echo-server.port}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And EchoServer class:

```
package chapter2.server;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class EchoServer {
    private final int port;

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(args.length);
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: " + EchoServer.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " <port>"
            );
            return;
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        new EchoServer(port).start();
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        final EchoServerHandler serverHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(serverHandler);
                        }
                    });

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            System.out.println(EchoServer.class.getName() +
                    " started and listening for connections on " + f.channel().localAddress());
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the message while running maven:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/adalyu/workspace/NettyExperiment "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61190:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1 -Dexec.workingdir=/Users/louis/workspace/NettyExperiment "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath chapter2.server.EchoServer" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java exec:exec
```

As you can see, the args

```
"-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath chapter2.server.EchoServer"
```

contains the class name but for some reason the argument is not picked up. I am following the public doc for maven plugin: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html. Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: You can execute it from the Maven tool windows. Go to the plugin section, expand the `exec` plugin and run the `exec:java`.

Comment: @W-S no there is no exec plugin in there. This one is imported as dependency not installed from intellij

Comment: Did you open the Maven tool windows located on the right side of Intellij? If you don't see that you can run the `exec:java` from the Run/Debug Configurations windows after adding new configuration for Maven .

Comment: Aha. I tried in the tool window and It shows "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: chapter2.server.EchoServer". I changed the path for the class but none of them work. Do you have any idea why? Also am I support to run the project from the tool window instead of click "Run -> EchoServer"

Comment: I am not sure why but can you try to recompile/rebuild your project and execute the exec plugin again.

Comment: the java goal of the exec plugin takes string[] as arguments, not argument as the exec goal. thats a bit weird. but maybe just try <arguments>${echo-server.port}</arguments>? instead of nested <argument>. See: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#arguments and https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#arguments